# how to keep a user login even if they close the app? I'm using swift 3, and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, xcode8

I'm new to coding and to Stack overflow, I'm trying to have a user stay logged in even after they close the app. I also don't want them to always see the login in screen. how do I do i go about keeping the user Login even if they close the app and re-open the app. I'm using Swift 3.0, Xcode 8, and Firebase.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper


class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pwField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.dismissKeyboard))
        //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
        //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard emailField.text != "", pwField.text != "" else {return}

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: pwField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if user != nil {
                let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController")

                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Below is my UsersViewController code it has the log-out button**

```
import UIKit
```

import Firebase

class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

var user = [User]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    retrieveUsers()
}


func retrieveUsers() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.user.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid != FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String {
                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
    checkFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count 
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let key = ref.child("users").childByAutoId().key

    var isFollower = false

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (ke, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                    isFollower = true

                    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following/\(ke)").removeValue()
                    ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).child("followers/\(ke)").removeValue()

                    self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
                }
            }
        }
        if !isFollower {
            let following = ["following/\(key)" : self.user[indexPath.row].userID]
            let followers = ["followers/\(key)" : uid]

            ref.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(following as Any as! [AnyHashable : Any])
            ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).updateChildValues(followers)

            self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}


func checkFollowing(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in following {
                if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                    self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                }
            }
        }
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}






@IBAction func logOutPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    do {

        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {

            // Remove User Session from device
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginViewController

        }

    } catch let signOutError as NSError {

        // handle logout error

    }
}
```

}

extension UIImageView {

```
func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

Firebase Auth can handle this for you. Like with Firebase Database, Auth works by setting up listeners. You can listen for an existing user in your App Delegate like so:

```
final class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    private let auth = FIRAuth.auth()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        auth?.addStateDidChangeListener { [weak self] (_, user) in
            if let user = user {
                // user is already logged in
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where would i add this?

Comment: I would put it in the App Delegate as I did, so you can change your window's root view controller whenever the state changes.

Comment: It still doesn't keep them logged in after you close the app.

Comment: It does. Provided sign in was successful, Firebase Auth holds onto the user.

Comment: do i need to put something in the comment section for it to work?

Comment: Yes... whatever logic you want to trigger when the user is logged in or out.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is successfully logged in, put their UID in UserDefaults to store the session like so:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid, forKey: "user_uid_key")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Then, whatever is the first View Controller that your apps loads, check for that key in the `viewDidAppear()` like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user_uid_key") != nil {
        // send them to a new view controller or do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Put the UserDefaults in the success block of the IBAction/Function where you register/login your user like shown below:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

            if user != nil {
                // Login success
                // Saves User UID to UserDefaults  
                UserDefaults.standard.set(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid, forKey: "USER_KEY_UID")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


            }
            else {  
                // login error

  })
```

Remove the UserDefault when the user logs out:

```
@IBAction func logoutButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    do {

        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {

            // Remove User Session from device
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "USER_KEY_UID")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
            present("TheVCYouWantToSendTheUserTo", animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    } catch let signOutError as NSError {

        // handle logout error
    }
}
```

UPDATED:

You forgot to include UserDefaults in your Login func. This is why it gives you an error. Add this to you login IBAction.

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    guard emailField.text != "", pwField.text != "" else {return}

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: pwField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)

// You forgot to save User UID to UserDefaults here... 
                UserDefaults.standard.set(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid, forKey: "uid")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        }

        if user != nil {
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController")

            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: where do i put the user defaults code? or is it under same section

Comment: I've updated the code above to make it more readable. See if that works for you

Comment: Firebase Auth already persists through app launches without UserDefaults.

Comment: it works like it automatically goes to the view controller but if i press sign out which will take me back to the login page it automatically sign-in again how do i fix this so that if I'm logged out it doesn't auto-login

Comment: for the code that removes the user default do i put this in the loginviewcontroller code or where the logout button is?

Comment: You want the user to click on a button that logs them out, remove the User Defaults key in the same logout button block code and move the user back to a login screen/view controller.

Comment: i think i did it wrong but i added the code to the button the logs them out and it just sends them to the login page, but the code to auto login users from login page sends them logged back in.

Comment: also USER_KEY_UID send an error or doesn't allow anything to happen but when i put uid it seems to send why is that?

Comment: I added my usersviewcontroller code can you please take a look at it and let me know why its not logging out?

Comment: @Brandon Once the user was logged in, you forgot to save that their uid in UserDefaults. And when you try to log them out, UserDefaults can't find the uid key because it doesn't exist. See my Update above

Comment: so how do i go about having them be logged out, when they press logout? and not be automatically logged back in if they pressed the logout button?

Comment: @Brandon that's what UserDefaults do!